# How to run a system command using Qt?

Tags: qt, command-line

I need to execute a system command in Qt and provide an argument for the command.

For example, opening a text file with `gedit`:

```
gedit /home/oDx/Documents/a.txt
```

But the path `/home/oDx/Documents/a.txt` will be in a variable like `docPath`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
QProcess process;
process.start("gedit", QStringList() << docPath);
```

the same as above

```
QProcess process;
process.start("gedit", QStringList() << "/home/oDx/Documents/a.txt");
```

Also, read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).

Answer (score 17):

[QProcess::execute()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute-1) may be helpful, although is deprecated:

```
QProcess::execute("gedit /home/oDx/Documents/a.txt");
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Qt 6.0, you can use [QProcess::startCommand](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#startCommand):

```cpp
QProcess process;
process.startCommand("gedit /home/oDx/Documents/a.txt");
```