# Run Windows PowerShell command with Qt

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, qt, command-line

Following [this post](https://superuser.com/a/812902/571029), I intent to run this command in my Qt 5.12.6 application on Windows 10 with admin privileges:

```bsh
powershell -Command "agent.exe  -Verb runAs"
```

My `agent.exe` is next to my Qt application executable, i.e. its parent directory would be `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`.

---

Inspired by [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3227845/3405291), my C++/Qt code looks like:

```cpp
m_agent = new QProcess(this);

QString agentName = "/agent.exe";
// "agent.exe" executable is next to application executable
QString agentPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + agentName;
QStringList args = QStringList();
// I'm not sure how to compose `args`
args << "-Command"; // ?
args << agentPath; // ?
args << "-Verb"; // ?
args << "runAs"; // ?
m_agent->start("powershell ", args);
```

My current `args`, composed above, is *not* starting the `agent.exe`.

My questions is: how should I compose `args` to be able to run my Windows PowerShell command with Qt?

Comment: As a small note, you can chain calls to `<<`, like so: `auto args = QStringList() << "-Command" << agentPath << "-Verb" << "runAs";` or use the initializer_list constructor: `QStringList args = { "-Command", agentPath, "-Verb", "runAs" };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some [observations](https://superuser.com/a/1511999/571029) helped with fixing the problem.

Now the `agent.exe` is run as admin with this code:

```cpp
QString agentName = "/agent.exe";
QString agentPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + agentName;
QStringList args = QStringList();
args << "-Command";
args << "Start-Process";
args << agentPath;
args << "-Verb";
args << "runAs";
m_agent->start("powershell", args);
```

### UPDATE

Alternatively, you can do this as suggested by @Botje

```cpp
QString agentName = "/agent.exe";
QString agentPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + agentName;
QStringList args = QStringList();
args = QStringList({"-Command", QString("Start-Process %1 -Verb runAs").arg(agentPath)});
m_agent->start("powershell", args);
```

Comment: Note that the command-line invocation `powershell -Command "agent.exe  -Verb runAs"` corresponds to `args={"-Command", QString("%1 -Verb runAs").arg(agentPath)}`. You can escape the quoting misery by passing a [base64-encoded command](https://mikefrobbins.com/2017/06/15/simple-obfuscation-with-powershell-using-base64-encoding/) instead.

Comment: @Botje Just thought you missed the `"Start-Process"` argument =)